# AOP not working with internal method call

Tags: aop, aspectj

may be this is a duplicate question I am not sure. so please ping me if its exactly duplicate. But as far as I have searched this is little different than what is mentioned in the similar questions.
So posting. Any help is appreciated.

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {
  @Pointcut("@annotation(com.home.CustomAnnotation)")
  public void myPointCut() {}

  @Around(value = "myPointCut")
  public void aroundAnnotation(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    syso("aspect working");
  }
}
```

```java
public interface MyInterface {
  default void doProcess(){
    myProcess();
  }

  public void myProcess();
}
```

```java
@Component
public class MyImplClass implements MyInterface {
  @CustomAnnotation
  public void myProcess(){
    syso("myProcess of MyImplClass");
  }
}
```

```java
public class MyBusinessService {
  @Autowired
  private MyInterface myInterfaceRef;

  public void myService() {
    myInterfaceRef.doProcess();
  }
}
```

I also have these dependencies

```java
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:2.7.15'
implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.7'
implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.6'
```

and I am expecting that every time myProcess() method is invoked - then the advice "aspect working" would be printed. But it is not happening so. I understand that it is because AOP is not able to handle normal method invocation which is happening inside doProcess().

But how easily can I make this work? I tried this.myProcess() instead of myProcess() inside doProcess()  but it does not work - when compiled --> "this." is omitted.

As the MyInterface is an interface --> I am not able to use self reference autowired. Kindly help if you know some cool way to deal with this.

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate and Spring AOP (by default) will not work with internal method calls. Prefixing with this etc. makes it still an internal method call. If you want this you will need to use full blown AspectJ with either load- or compile timeweaving to modify the bytecode of the class.